# Unable to send email through Exchange server in a PHP based website (Question2Answers)

Tags: php, email, smtp, exchange-server

I am using a php based website in my company for question and answers so I had set the smtp details to send and receive mails to users, now my company moved to Exchange server for emails.After that my php application is not able to send any emails to the users inside my company.

I tried with the new exchange server settings and luckily one mail got send but when again I tried later no success.

Please guide me if any thing else I need to set. Or SMTP wont work for exchange server?

Thanks,
Ashok Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

There are a numbers of things that might make Exchange deny access.

Firstly, check TLS Authentication

I've had luck using http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

As a last resort you can create a receive connector with only basic auth on the exchange server set to receive emails only from your PHP servers IP address. I recommend doing this using a local IP over a VPN. You will need to edit the existing receive connectors so their listening IP range does not include the IP address used on the new receive connectors.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I just changed the SMTP authentication to none and removed the username and password. Now I am able to send email in my domain only.